# What is the relationship between $x$ and $x^{1+\sin(x)}$ with respect to their growth speed?

Tags: calculus

How to calculate

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to +\infty}  \frac{x^{\sin(x)+1}}{x} 
\end{align}

By looking at $x^{1+\sin(x)}$ plot I can see that since it oscillates between $1$ and $x^2$
the limit does not exist. So my main question is:

If the limit does not exist then what is the growth relationship between the two functions?

And my minor question is: how to prove that this limit does not exist?

Comment: Since $\sin{x}$ oscillates, the limit you want to compute does not exist, i.e. it does not converge to a single value.

Comment: so what about the growth relationship between two functions ?

Comment: What do you mean by the term `growth relationship`?

Comment: do they have the same growth speed or is one of them faster than the other?

Comment: To me this question makes no sense. Naturally, the denominator grows as $O(x)$. The numerator varies from $O(x)$ as $\sin(x) = 1$ or $O(1/x)$ as $\sin(x) = -1$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the sequence $x_n=n\pi$ which gives 
$$\frac{(x_n)^{\sin x_n}}{x_n}=\frac1{x_n}\underset{n\to\infty}\rightarrow0$$
and the sequence $y_n=\frac\pi2+2n\pi$ that gives
$$\frac{(y_n)^{\sin y_n}}{y_n}=1\underset{n\to\infty}\rightarrow1.$$
You have found two sequences going to infinity that have different limits.
Therefore, there is no limit for $x^{\sin x}/x$ when $x\to\infty$.